# How to change autoresizingMask via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

This is somewhat a longwinded explanation please bear with me.

I am using 3 custom buttons (TeamMemberButton, TeamStatButton, TeamPerformanceButton) in my application. Each one is added several times to a UIView "tab" and these tabs swap in and out of a UIScrollView upon button click.

To help you visualize this is what it looks like at this point https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2xW8.jpg. The views currently labelled "Button" switch which tab is visible below the button bar. My custom buttons are the cells that contain the images and the blue or purple player names e.g. "Vixcellent"

I initially only had 1 of these custom buttons and recently had to create 2 more for the new tabs and ran into problems. When creating the new UIView subclasses I first created the .h and .m files and then later created a UserInterface View from the file creation menu.

For some reason when adding the two new buttons manually to a tab via:

```
- (void)setup {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    int lastY = 0;
    int height = 54;
    for (Participant *participant in self.matchExtended.blueTeam) {
        TeamStatButton *blueMember = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TeamStatButton" owner:self options:nil][0];
        [blueMember setFrame:CGRectMake(0, lastY, self.bounds.size.width, height)];
        [blueMember configureWithParticipant:participant];
        [self addSubview:blueMember];
        lastY += height;
    }
    for (Participant *participant in self.matchExtended.purpleTeam) {
        TeamStatButton *purpleMember = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TeamStatButton" owner:self options:nil][0];
        [purpleMember configureWithParticipant:participant];
        [purpleMember setFrame:CGRectMake(0, lastY, self.bounds.size.width, height)];
        [self addSubview:purpleMember];
        lastY += height;
    }

    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = lastY;
    self.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Immediately after the `setup` function had completed all the subviews changed their height from 54 to 594 (roughly the height of their parent view). I suspected that autolayout was the cause but after checking through every single inspector tab between the two custom button types I could find no difference.

After 3 hours of wasting time I found that in the .xib source the following line was the culprit.

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
```

Changing this line to the following fixed my problem in the new UIView subclasses:

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

My question is what is this `autoresizingMask` tag and is there any way to change it through the Interface Builder if a situation like this occurs?

Thanks for the help!